# function simplification with binomial coefficients

Tags: algorithms, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

we are given a function $$f(n,k) = \sum_{s=0}^{s=n} \sum_{r=s}^{r=n} \sum_{t=0}^{t=s} \frac {\binom nr \binom rs \binom st t(3k^2)^{t/2} I(t)}{(s+1)} $$. $ (n c r)$ known as Binomial Coefficient denotes the number of ways to choose an unordered subset of r elements from a fixed set of n elements.

$$I(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \equiv 0\ (mod\ 4) \\ 0 & x \equiv 1\ (mod\ 4) \\ -1 & x \equiv 2\ (mod\ 4) \\ 0 & x \equiv 3\ (mod\ 4) \\ \end{cases} $$.

We have to find the value of f(n,k) (modulo 10^9+21).
Integers n and k are given to us.

Can anyone please help to simplify the above-given function?

Comment: I don't want to make a mistake trying to interpret the query.  Please see [MathJax Help](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: @user2661923 i have edited.please check it

Comment: You need to use the "\$" sign around the expressions, before and after, or "\$$", try them out to see the differences, but without them the formatting doesn't happen.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó i have edited my question .please check it.

Comment: @user2661923 have a look.

Comment: Just keep editing till all the formulas look fine to you, you see the same as we. The next step is to add what have you tried so far to solve the question, otherwise you will likely get downvotes.

Comment: sir I am unable to simplify the given function.That is where I am sticking. Even some simplification hint will  provide me the path to solve this question

Comment: please reply anyone with his approach

Comment: I spent a couple of hours with this problem and wasn't able to solve it.  Your query has reached the point where mathSE reviewers will classify it as a [no clue query](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).  It's your decision whether you want the assistance of mathSE reviewers (more knowledgeable than I am). ...see next comment.

Comment: These reviewers are going to be looking for you to edit your query to provide the following information (1) What is the source of the query?  Is this from a contest?  If so, which exact contest?  If not, is this query from a book or a class?  If so, which specific book or class? (2) Assuming that the query is from a book or class, what is the query's background?  That is, what theorems or previously solved problems from the book or class do you think might be relevant to the query?  ...see next comment

Comment: (3) Regard the background theorems or previously solved problems as tools to be used to attack the query.  Please show some effort in trying to use these tools to attack the query. ::: With regard to all of these questions, please do **not** respond with a comment.  Instead, please respond by directly editing your query.

Comment: (Looking at "10^9+21", I'm sure it is a _programming challenge_. Hands down.)